# onclick event not working for multiple functions together

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick, submit-button

onclick event

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="login100-form-btn" onClick="this.validate-input">
Create Account
</button>
```

and

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="login100-form-btn" onClick="this.disabled=true">
Create Account
</button>
```

works separately but

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="login100-form-btn" onClick="this.validate-input; this.disabled=true">
Create Account
</button>
```

does not work together. Please suggest me how can I

- validate-input.
- disable button once clicked.
  TOGETHER

**EDIT**

I have downloaded this code from colorlib.com. When I click the submit button two times together, it gives an error. So I want to disable the submit button once clicked.

Please checkout my *jQuery*

```
var input = $('.validate-input .input100');

$('.validate-form').on('submit', function() {
  var check = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (validate(input[i]) == false) {
      showValidate(input[i]);
      check = false;
    }
  }

  return check;
});


$('.validate-form .input100').each(function() {
  $(this).focus(function() {
    hideValidate(this);
  });
});

function validate(input) {
  if ($(input).attr('type') == 'email' || $(input).attr('name') == 'email') {
    if ($(input).val().trim().match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/) == null) {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    if ($(input).val().trim() == '') {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

function showValidate(input) {
  var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

  $(thisAlert).addClass('alert-validate');
}

function hideValidate(input) {
  var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

  $(thisAlert).removeClass('alert-validate');
}
```

Comment: You need `()` after a function name to call the function. But `validate-input` isn't an allowable function name.

Comment: `-` is the subtraction operator. `this.validate-input` is subtracting the value of `input` from `this.validate`.

Comment: I don't believe the first snippet works by itself.

Comment: I have added my jquery. Please check it.

Comment: disabling a submit button is going to cause problems if you are using a traditional form submission back to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add disabling the submit button to the validation function.

```
$('.validate-form').on('submit', function() {
  var check = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (validate(input[i]) == false) {
      showValidate(input[i]);
      check = false;
    }
  }
  if (check) {
    $(this).find(":submit").prop("disabled", true);
  }
  return check;
});
```

Comment: button does not get disabled :(
clicking multiple times still leads to get multiple entries.

Comment: Try now with different value for the attribute.

Comment: setAttribute ?? Is that jQuery? it should be `.prop()`

Comment: No, it should be `.attr()`

Comment: Really? https://api.jquery.com/prop/ let's read what the documentation says *"Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The **.prop()** method should be **used to set disabled** and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value."*